# Input Range type - Low Search

Tags: search, database, low-search

I am working on an online directory that will allow users to use the input range type element(a slider) to search for prices. Can this be used with low search this element, or would anyone recommend any other add-ons that would allow for the slider/input range to search my db whilst still using EE.

Thanks

Jam

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Low Search is front-end agnostic. That is, it doesn't really matter what input fields you use in the search form on the front-end, as long as you name them correctly, so Low Search understands them. Input fields always relate to tag parameters: the input name should be identical to the parameter you would use in the Results tag.

In the case of [ranges](http://gotolow.com/addons/low-search/docs/tags#form-tag-ranges), you can either use a single parameter (using the *from* and *to* values 1 to 10 in this example):

```
range:field_name="1;10"
```

Or split it in two parameters:

```
range-from:field_name="1" range-to:field_name="10"
```

The `field_name` is the field you're targeting for the range.

Translated to html input elements, this is:

```
<input name="range:field_name" value="1;10">
```

...and...

```
<input name="range-from:field_name" value="1">
<input name="range-to:field_name" value="10">
```

You can then get the posted values of these parameters using the parameter name, prefixed with `low_search_`, so:

- `{low_search_range:field_name}`
- `{low_search_range-from:field_name}`
- `{low_search_range-to:field_name}`

You don't need to use `<input>`s per se; you could also use `<select>`s. As long as the `name` attribute equals the parameter name.

So, as long as you make sure the names and values are as they should be, you can use any input element you like. How you implement it, is up to you.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Implementing as we speak, appreciate the feedback !

Comment: Low has the `ranges` docs & examples been removed from the docs? Starting to do preliminary research as I'm building a site that will be using ranges for search parameters, thanks!

Comment: Docs had a makeover since Low Search 3. Ranges Filter docs are here: http://gotolow.com/addons/low-search/docs/filters#ranges